# DCG reversing a string of binary bits

Tags: prolog, dcg

I want to write a (Prolog) DCG which takes in strings of the form `a2rev(a)` where a is a string of binary bits, e.g. 1012101, 001121100, 0111002001110. My idea was the following :

```
reverse([])    --> [].
reverse([H|T]) --> reverse(T), [H].

s--> [2].
s--> a,2,b.
a--> [0];[1].
reverse(a,b).
```

This doesn't work - I am unsure whether I am calling the `reverse` function incorrectly or if `a --> [0];[1]` makes sense.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You are not mixing the dcg and code properly. Here `b//1` extracts a binary sequence and `s//1` extracts a binary sequence which has your required property.

```
b([]) --> [].
b([0 | X]) --> [0], b(X).
b([1 | X]) --> [1], b(X).
s(X) --> b(X), [2], {reverse(X, Y)}, b(Y).
```

The reverse constraint is added in a `{}` block using the `reverse/2` predicate. If instead you want to use `reverse//1` dcg itself you can replace `s//1` above with:

```
s(X) --> b(X), [2], reverse(X).
```

This gives

```
?- phrase(s(X), [1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1]).
X = [1, 1, 0]
```

For better clarity of what is going on when mixing code and dcg try checking `listing(b)` and `listing(s)`.

Comment: Hi, that is helpful thank you. I was under the impression that I could do so without the functors having arity (or not looking like they do at least) - like this : reverse([])    --> [].
reverse([H|T]) --> reverse(T), [H].
````
b --> [].
b --> [0], b.
b --> [1], b.
s-->[2].
s --> b, s, reverse(b).

Comment: You can remove it for `s//1`, but for binary strings `b//1` you need them for the reverse constraint.

Comment: You are trying to pass an argument to reverse//1, what should it be? You are writing `reverse(b)` but `b` itself is a dcg so you need to extract the first binary sequence. Hence `b(X), [2], reverse(X)` will work. So you can do `s --> b(X), [2], reverse(X).` if you do not want additional argument to `s`.